# Can I create some small views including created views to use it in mainPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can I create a view including Entry Progress bar or others to make a view which I can use in other places?

for example I want to create a card view which I can use to list the lists.

I can only write  in the list not to write the card in every list.

Comment: Have you created a card view successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom view and use it in the `MainPage` or other `Pages`, `Views` you want.

To create a custom view, add a `new item` --> `ContentView`,let's call it `CardView`:

In .cs of `CardView`:

```
public partial class CardView : ContentView
{
    public CardView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In xaml of CardView, add your `labels`,`progressbar`, `entry` there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App35.CardView">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
            <ProgressBar Progress="0.5" />
            <Entry Placeholder="I'm entry"/>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

To use it in `MainPage`, in `listView` or in the `page`:

```
<StackLayout>

    <projectName:CardView  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <ListView  x:Name="listView" RowHeight="70">

        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>

                    <projectName:CardView  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

I upload a sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/custom-cardView) and you can check.

Comment: thankyou @Jack Hua and how to specify a variable by binding?

Comment: @daotian Can you please mark/accept this answer so that we can help more people with same problem? how to specify a variable by binding? I saw you opened a new thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723225/how-to-create-a-bindable-property-in-a-custom-contentview) and there is already an answer there you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using ContentView, if you want to use it as views
Or you can make ViewCells if you want to use it in ListViews. Its easy and almost every project does that.
You can refer this link :- https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/

Let me know if you have more questions on this. Thanks!