# how to create a bindable property in a custom contentView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a custom ContentView with a Image and a Label.

I also created a property of ImageUrl and LabelText.

I want this ContentView an receive a Binding value in a listview

```
<MyCustomContentView ImageUrl="{Binding Image}" LabelText="{Binding Text}" />
```

but it says there is no bindable property.how to create it?

Comment: Use [bindable-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) in your MyCustomContentView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code and paste it below the constructor of the MyCustomContentView class in the code behind file.

```
        public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelText), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomContentView), default(string));
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageUrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageUrl), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomContentView), default(string));

        public string LabelText { get => (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); set => SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        public string ImageUrl { get => (string)GetValue(ImageUrlProperty); set => SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, value); }
```

Let me know if you have further difficulties